# AngularJS how to run javascript after scope change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Hi I had some Java scripts specific to a view. However, the script doesnt execute when angularjs loads the view. First time script run but script didnt execute when changed scope .The main index.html dont include this javascript code. This code in home.html . Index.html loads home.html but only one time working this javascript code.

```
$('#layerslider').layerSlider({
    skin : 'fullwidth',
    hoverPrevNext           : true,
    navStartStop            : false,
    navButtons              : false,
    autoPlayVideos          : false,
    animateFirstLayer       : false

});


var $carousel = $('.recent-blog-jc, .recent-work-jc');

var scrollCount;

 function adjustScrollCount() {
if( $(window).width() < 768 ) {
    scrollCount = 1;
} else {
    scrollCount = 3;
}

}

function adjustCarouselHeight() {

$carousel.each(function() {
    var $this    = $(this);
    var maxHeight = -1;
    $this.find('li').each(function() {
        maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
    });
    $this.height(maxHeight);
});
}
function initCarousel() {
adjustCarouselHeight();
adjustScrollCount();
var i = 0;
var g = {};
$carousel.each(function() {
    i++;

    var $this = $(this);
    g[i] = $this.jcarousel({
        animation           : 600,
        scroll              : scrollCount
    });
    $this.jcarousel('scroll', 0);
     $this.prev().find('.jcarousel-prev').bind('active.jcarouselcontrol', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).bind('inactive.jcarouselcontrol', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).jcarouselControl({
        target: '-='+scrollCount,
        carousel: g[i]
    });

    $this.prev().find('.jcarousel-next').bind('active.jcarouselcontrol', function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }).bind('inactive.jcarouselcontrol', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }).jcarouselControl({
        target: '+='+scrollCount,
        carousel: g[i]
    });

    $this.touchwipe({
    wipeLeft: function() {
        $this.jcarousel('scroll','+='+scrollCount);
    },
    wipeRight: function() {
        $this.jcarousel('scroll','-='+scrollCount);
    }
});

});
}
$(function(){ 
$(window).load(function(){
initCarousel(); 
});
});
$(window).resize(function () {
$carousel.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.jcarousel('destroy');
});
initCarousel();
});
```

Comment: `$scope.$apply()` If I understood correctly

Comment: you need to rewrite this into a directive. It won't work triggered by window load event if you are using angular to render the elements

Answer (score 0):

Just add `$scope.$apply()` as close to the async event as possible, though keep in mind this is not best practice (you should try to do everything you can "*the Angular way*").

Comment: To clarify, the `angular way` simply means to restrict all `dom` changes to `directives` where `scope.$apply()` can be used as needed.  AngularJS ships with jQuery-lite for use in directives and many projects do not even need to require jQuery.  You may enjoy this: https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem with angular directive. I get element with angular.element(document.querySelector('....')).  I used ng-repeat in the directive template.

```
directive('carousel', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: false,

    template: ' <div class="blank floated"><div class="four columns carousel-intro"><section class="entire"><h3>{{homepage.header4}}</h3><p>{{homepage.text4}}</p></section><div class="carousel-navi"><div id="work-prev" class="arl active jcarousel-prev"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="jcarousel-control-prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a></div><div id="work-next" class="arr active jcarousel-next"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="jcarousel-control-next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a></div></div><div class="clearfix"></div></div><section class="jcarousel recent-work-jc"><ul><li class="four columns" ng-repeat="work in works"><a href="#/projeler/{{work.id}}" class="portfolio-item" ><figure><img src="{{work.image}}" alt=""/><figcaption class="item-description"><h5>{{work.title}}</h5><span>{{work.type}}</span></figcaption></figure></a></li></ul></section></div>',
    link: function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var container = $(element);
        var carousel = container.children('.jcarousel')

        carousel.jcarousel({
            wrap: 'circular'
        });

        scope.$watch(attrs.images, function (value) {
            carousel.jcarousel('reload');
        });

        angular.element(document.querySelector('#work-prev')).children('.jcarousel-control-prev')
            .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

        angular.element(document.querySelector('#work-next')).children('.jcarousel-control-next')
            .jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });
    }
}

});
```